# net.tcp WCF self hosted service can't connect through IP but it connectes through localhost

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wcf, hosting

I have windows server 2012 with IIS 8.5

When I try to access the silverlight project in the same machine using address http://localhost/silverlightproject, everything goes right
but when I use the IP address http:///silverlightproject can't connect 
this problem only happens on windows 2012, I tried on windows 7,windows server 2008 and 2003 all was fine

I have made the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the default IP root as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<policy>

  <allow-from http-request-headers="*">

    <domain uri="*" />

  </allow-from>

  <grant-to>

    <socket-resource port="4502-4534" protocol="tcp" />

  </grant-to>

</policy>
```

I also added crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

please help

Comment: After 2 days of search I found the solution ,, it is all about bindings in IIS, I have to add net.tcp binding to net.tcp:808:*

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of search I found the solution ,,
 it is all about bindings in IIS
 I have to add net.tcp binding to 808:*